# Updating Modal with controller model

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to use dynamic content inside my modal using angular controller model.

My codepen: codepen.io/anon/pen/dpJxa1

I am trying to increment $scope.count whenever user clicks Create contact button inside the modal. This count will be used to populate first name in the modal.

Even though the count is increasing which is shown in alert, it is not reflecting the modal. How can I listen for the changes in my model and show it in modal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `.show()` method on your modal again, after each time you want the modal to update content. So add something like `$scope.myModal.show();` to your increment function.

Comment: I am using show method after updating the model. I can see the model is update but the latest data is not showing in modal UI.